# "NaN" error when using operator in my calculator app

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

So I have been working on a Calculator app off a tutorial I got online. Everything's fine so far but I can't seem work to out what's causing this "NaN" error in my application every time I try to use the operator buttons. I'll attach screenshots of the code and app. Sorry if I'm vague I'm new to coding and just trying to learn.

My MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.calculator_prjct;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil;
import android.app.Activity;
import com.example.calculator_prjct.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private ActivityMainBinding binding;
  private static final char ADDITION = '+';
  private static final char SUBTRACTION = '-';
  private static final char MULTIPLICATION = '*';
  private static final char DIVISION = '/';

  private char CURRENT_ACTION;

  private double valueOne = Double.NaN;
  private double valueTwo;

  private DecimalFormat decimalFormat;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##########");

    final ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);

    binding.buttonDot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + ".");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonZero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "0");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "1");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "2");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "3");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonFour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "4");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonFive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "5");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonSix.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "6");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonSeven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "7");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonEight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "8");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonNine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "9");
        }
    });


    binding.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            computeCalculation();
            CURRENT_ACTION = ADDITION;
            binding.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "+");
            binding.editText.setText(null);
        }
    });

    binding.buttonSubtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            computeCalculation();
            CURRENT_ACTION = SUBTRACTION;
            binding.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "-");
            binding.editText.setText(null);
        }
    });

    binding.buttonMultiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            computeCalculation();
            CURRENT_ACTION = MULTIPLICATION;
            binding.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "*");
            binding.editText.setText(null);
        }
    });

    binding.buttonDivide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            computeCalculation();
            CURRENT_ACTION = DIVISION;
            binding.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "/");
            binding.editText.setText(null);
        }
    });

    binding.buttonEquals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            computeCalculation();
            binding.infoTextView.setText(binding.infoTextView.getText().toString() +
                    decimalFormat.format(valueTwo) + " = " + decimalFormat.format(valueOne));
            valueOne = Double.NaN;
            CURRENT_ACTION = '0';
        }
    });

    binding.buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (binding.editText.getText().length() > 0) {
                CharSequence currentText = binding.editText.getText();
                binding.editText.setText(currentText.subSequence(0, currentText.length() - 1));
            } else {
                valueOne = Double.NaN;
                valueTwo = Double.NaN;
                binding.editText.setText("");
                binding.infoTextView.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}

private void computeCalculation() {
    if (!Double.isNaN(valueOne)) {
        valueTwo = Double.parseDouble(binding.editText.getText().toString());
        binding.editText.setText(null);

        if (CURRENT_ACTION == ADDITION)
            valueOne = this.valueOne + valueTwo;
        else if (CURRENT_ACTION == SUBTRACTION)
            valueOne = this.valueOne - valueTwo;
        else if (CURRENT_ACTION == MULTIPLICATION)
            valueOne = this.valueOne * valueTwo;
        else if (CURRENT_ACTION == DIVISION)
            valueOne = this.valueOne / valueTwo;
    } else {
        try {
            valueOne = Double.parseDouble(binding.editText.getText().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

}

My activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/infoTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/infoTextView"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:lines="2"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSeven"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:text="7"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonFour"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-87dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSeven"
    android:text="4"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonFive"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSeven"
    android:text="5"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSix"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="89dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSeven"
    android:text="6"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonOne"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="-1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-89dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="96dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSeven"
    android:text="1"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonTwo"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="95dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSeven"
    android:text="2"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonThree"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:layout_marginLeft="88dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="97dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSeven"
    android:text="3"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDot"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-86dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSeven"
    android:text="."
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonZero"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="144dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSeven"
    android:text="0"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonEquals"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="179dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="91dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="145dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSeven"
    android:text="="
    android:textSize="20sp" />


<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="265dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="177dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="197dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSeven"
    android:text="C"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonEight"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSeven"
    android:text="8"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonNine"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/editText"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonEight"
    android:text="9"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDivide"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/buttonNine"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonNine"
    android:text="/"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonMultiply"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/buttonDivide"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-88dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="48dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonDivide"
    android:text="*"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonSubtract"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/buttonMultiply"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-86dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonMultiply"
    android:text="-"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/buttonSubtract"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-89dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="49dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonSubtract"
    android:text="+"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
</layout>
```

Screenshot of the actual error
["NaN Error on all operator buttons"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIVoF.png)

Comment: I noticed that you call computCalculation() before you set CURRENT_ACTION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you didn't check whether or not the `EditText` is empty in the respective `onClick` method of all the operator `buttons`. Add code like this to all of the operator `buttons` :

```
binding.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(binding.editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter number before performing operation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            computeCalculation();
            CURRENT_ACTION = ADDITION;

            //if editText was empty then valueOne would still be NaN
            //and infoTextView will show NaN+ with this line of code

            binding.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "+");
            binding.editText.setText(null);
        }
    });
```

Full Activity Code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainBinding binding;
private static final char ADDITION = '+';
private static final char SUBTRACTION = '-';
private static final char MULTIPLICATION = '*';
private static final char DIVISION = '/';

private char CURRENT_ACTION;

private double valueOne = Double.NaN;
private double valueTwo;

private DecimalFormat decimalFormat;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
    View view = binding.getRoot();
    setContentView(view);


    decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.##########");

    binding.buttonDot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + ".");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonZero.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "0");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "1");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "2");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonThree.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "3");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonFour.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "4");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonFive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "5");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonSix.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "6");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonSeven.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "7");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonEight.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "8");
        }
    });

    binding.buttonNine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            binding.editText.setText(binding.editText.getText() + "9");
        }
    });


    binding.buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(binding.editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter number before performing operation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            computeCalculation();
            CURRENT_ACTION = ADDITION;
            binding.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "+");
            binding.editText.setText(null);
        }
    });

    binding.buttonSubtract.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(binding.editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter number before performing operation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            computeCalculation();
            CURRENT_ACTION = SUBTRACTION;
            binding.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "-");
            binding.editText.setText(null);
        }
    });

    binding.buttonMultiply.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(binding.editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter number before performing operation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            computeCalculation();
            CURRENT_ACTION = MULTIPLICATION;
            binding.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "*");
            binding.editText.setText(null);
        }
    });

    binding.buttonDivide.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(binding.editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter number before performing operation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            computeCalculation();
            CURRENT_ACTION = DIVISION;
            binding.infoTextView.setText(decimalFormat.format(valueOne) + "/");
            binding.editText.setText(null);
        }
    });

    binding.buttonEquals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(binding.editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter number before performing operation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            computeCalculation();
            binding.infoTextView.setText(binding.infoTextView.getText().toString() +
                    decimalFormat.format(valueTwo) + " = " + decimalFormat.format(valueOne));
            valueOne = Double.NaN;
            CURRENT_ACTION = '0';
        }
    });

    binding.buttonClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (binding.editText.getText().length() > 0) {
                CharSequence currentText = binding.editText.getText();
                binding.editText.setText(currentText.subSequence(0, currentText.length() - 1));
            } else {
                valueOne = Double.NaN;
                valueTwo = Double.NaN;
                binding.editText.setText("");
                binding.infoTextView.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
}

private void computeCalculation() {
    if (!Double.isNaN(valueOne)) {
        valueTwo = Double.parseDouble(binding.editText.getText().toString());
        binding.editText.setText(null);

        if (CURRENT_ACTION == ADDITION)
            valueOne = this.valueOne + valueTwo;
        else if (CURRENT_ACTION == SUBTRACTION)
            valueOne = this.valueOne - valueTwo;
        else if (CURRENT_ACTION == MULTIPLICATION)
            valueOne = this.valueOne * valueTwo;
        else if (CURRENT_ACTION == DIVISION)
            valueOne = this.valueOne / valueTwo;
    } else {
        try {
            valueOne = Double.parseDouble(binding.editText.getText().toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. I still get the same error. However, there's a nice non-clickable message that comes up when I click on an operator without entering a number.

Comment: did you add exactly this way  and to all of the operator button ? You need to check whether or not the EditText is empty at the starting of the method. If it is, its gonna show the Toast and should return without setting the `infoTextView` value. I tried myself with your code and it was working.

Comment: Wait, so you were able to add subtract and all that? Interesting...gimme a few. Thanks

Comment: yeah, I have that calculator app running without any trouble. Just add  
`if(binding.editText.getText().toString().isEmpty()) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Enter number before performing operation", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }`
this piece of code in your `btnAdd`, `btnSubtract`, and in every other operator's `onClick()` method.

Comment: Gotcha. Lemme just double check this.

Comment: Ok so I've double checked like six times now. It's still the same thing.

Comment: Okay I will edit my answer to post code of whole activity. That way, you can check if you did something wrong somewhere.

Comment: @Andy_431 Okay, check it now

Comment: Oh my goodness. It works! Bless your heart! Thank you so much, you've no idea how stressful this was. I'll need to go through my code and find out what was the issue. But in the meantime you have my utmost gratitude!

Comment: I can feel that pain. It's the same feeling when something we expect to work does not work.